# Python / Django - How to get all methods in a unittest class to share the same database?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, python-unittest, django-unittest

This is my code:

Link to my imports are here:
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/urlresolvers.py
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py
https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/status.py
https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/test.py

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase

class UserTests(APITestCase):
    def test_create_user(self):
        """
        Ensure we can create a new user object.
        """
        url = reverse('user-list')
        data = {'username': 'a', 'password': 'a', 'email': 'a@hotmail.com'}
        # Post the data to the URL to create the object
        response = self.client.post(url, data, format='json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        # Check the database to see if the object is created.
        # This check works.
        self.assertEqual(User.objects.count(), 1)

    def test_get_user(self):
        """
        Ensure we can get a list of user objects.
        """
        # This fails and returns an error
        self.assertEqual(User.objects.count(), 1)
```

When I run the test, it raises an error saying `AssertionError: 0 != 1` because in the function `test_get_user`, the user created in `test_create_user` is not visible. Is there a way for me to get all the methods in a class to share the same database so that if I create a user in `test_create_user`, I can access it in the methods which come below it?

Edit: The reason I want them to share the same database for all the methods is because all of my test cases in the `UserTests` class will need a user created so I don't want to have to repeat the same code all the time even when it is tested in `test_create_user`.

I know I can use `def setUp(self)` but I'm doing a "create user" test in my first method so I want to be able to test if I can create it first before creating it in `def setUp(self)`.

Comment: Please add `APITestCase` and your imports.

Comment: I think it is easier to create a separate test case to unittest user. It would basically test the code for creating users which could be used to prepopulate the DB in other test cases.

Comment: @SebastianWozny I added the link to the GitHub source code (it's the default Django and DRF source code).

Comment: @Ivan Hm, what exactly do you mean? Are you saying that I create my own class to unittest `test_create_user` and then a separate class to unittest everything else which depends on creating a user (so that I can just create the user  in the `def setUp(self)` method?).

Comment: Exactly, you shouldn't try to fit everything into one `TestCase`.

Comment: @Ivan The thing is, I want to fit every testcase which tests the `User` model (GET User, CREATE User, PATCH User, PUT User and DELETE User) into one class since they are all related.

Comment: Then add utility methods to reuse object creation code as suggested in @DanielRoseman's comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set up your data explicitly in each test. Tests must not depend on each other.

Comment: In my situation (see my edit at the bottom of my post) would you still recommend reusing the same part of the code (the part where I create the user) over and over in all my methods? Or is there a better way to do it? Note: I don't want to create the user in `def setUp(self)` because I want to be able to test if I can create a user first before creating it (the test is done in the first method - `def test_create_user(self)`.

Comment: No, you can just create the object directly via the ORM; no need to go via the post if you're not specifically testing that. But you can certainly put that into a separate utility method if you want.