# keep my data test when running TestCase in django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testcase

i have a initial_data command in my project and when i try to create my test database and run this command
"py manage.py initial_data" it's not working because this command makes data in main database and not test_database, actually can't understand which one is test_database.
so i give up to use this command,and i have other method to resolve my problem .
and i decided to create manually my initial_data.
initial_data command actually makes my required data in my other tables.
and why i try to create data?
because i have greater than 500 tests and this tests required to other test datas.
so i have this tests:

```
class BankServiceTest(TestCase):


    def setUp(self):
        self.bank_model = models.Bank
        self.country_model = models.Country

    def test_create_bank_object(self):
        self.bank_model.objects.create(name='bank')
        re1 = self.bank_model.objects.get(name='bank')
        self.assertEqual(re1.name, 'bank')

    def test_create_country_object(self):
        self.country_model.objects.create(name='country', code=100)
        bank = self.bank_model.objects.get(name='bank')
        re1 = self.country_model.objects.get(code=100)
        self.assertEqual(re1.name, 'country')
```

i want after running "test create bank object " to have first function datas in second function
actually this method Performs the command "initial_data".

so what is the method for this problem.

i used unit_test.TestCase but it not working for me.
this method actually makes test data in main data base and i do not want this method.
or maybe i used bad of this method.

actually i need to keep my data in running test.

Comment: This isn't really possible, tests aren't really run in a specific order so forget chaining data between tests, `test_create_country_object` might run before `test_create_bank_object` causing your tests to fail. Each test should be independent of the other since you are doing **unit testing**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python / Django - How to get all methods in a unittest class to share the same database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33323364/python-django-how-to-get-all-methods-in-a-unittest-class-to-share-the-same-d) Also see [Loading fixtures in django unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470634/loading-fixtures-in-django-unit-tests)

Comment: Well, I have to say that I found a solution to my question , and  found a method in testcases.py in django test and And I noticed that a function would rollback each of my tests after they finished. So I avoided this by overriding this function.